# Static Url Redirection in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to redirect `page1` to `something/page1` in my wordpress site.

i have tried the below rule in my htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^page1/$ something/page1? [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

i am not familiar in htaccess rules. but the redirection is not working.

can any one help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the content of the .htaccess file where the WP rule-set and the rules in your question are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```php
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Next line added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !page1    [NC]

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Next 3 lines added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page1  something/page1? [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

For permanent and visible redirection, replace [L] with [R=301,L] in the last rewrite rule.

Comment: Thank you @ faa. but i need to show "something/page1" in browser address bar. it is possible?

Comment: You are welcome. Check my answer for the way to do it (Last Line).